# How do I use Angular i18n for languages it doesn't appear to support?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, locale, angular-translate

I am using Angular i18n for German, English, Spanish, French, Italian, Portuguese, Russian, Ukrainian, Japanese, Korean, and Chinese.

These are all supported locales, but I've been tasked to include translations for **Cebuano, Samoan, Tagalog, and Tongan**. These do not appear to be supported locales in Angular i18n.

How do I still use Angular i18n with these four locales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular supports `i18n` Standard for location | globalization | internationalization.  When it comes to number,dates and so fort for names of days, months, etc. Angular relies on `$locale` service for example in the case of number the property `NUMBER_FORMATS`.

Here is the list of locations currently supported by angular:

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n/

Here is an example on how to support [german locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n):

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>

   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>

 </head>
</html>
```

If you want to dig more into or create your own you can search for `NUMBER_FORMATS` in any of the CDNs provided above and you will find what angular will use to format your numbers, this is an example:

```
"NUMBER_FORMATS": {
    "CURRENCY_SYM": "\u20ac",
    "DECIMAL_SEP": ",",
    "GROUP_SEP": ".",
...
```

Comment: But the question is how to support locales that are **not** in the CDN.

Comment: And the question is specifically about Angular Translate, not Angular i18n.

Comment: @Juhana I guess you just wanted a post to chat, I am out

Comment: @Dalorzo, thank you for your post. I did find the Tagalog version in the CDN you provided. I will manually create the other three locale files and post them to the same CDN.

Comment: @BillyBoJimBob, You should post the new angular-locale-xx-xx.js to the AngularJS team through a github pull request. Their project is https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n. To do a pull request, just follow this manual: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Comment: @BillyBoJimBob, I do not see your files added to the i18n project, but I could really use the samoan translation file, if you have it still. Will you please add it to the i18n repo, or post it somewhere where I can get to it? Thanks.

Comment: It appears user1209809 that spiffy2man posted a pull request today. Thank you for the reminder. His file and mine are very similar.

Comment: @BillyBiJimBob how about an up vote if this post helped you